# Finding a specific span element with a class using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

The html below is stored in a selenium WebDriver variable

```
<td colspan="2" class="pi_mailing_address"><strong>Mailing Address</strong>
        <div>
             <span class="ng-binding">1236 NW 167 ST </span>
             <span ng-show="property.mailingAddress.address2" class="ng-binding ng-hide">STE #</span>
             <span ng-show="property.mailingAddress.address3" class="ng-binding ng-hide">789</span>
             <span ng-show="property.mailingAddress.city" ng-class="{'inline':property.mailingAddress.city}" class="ng-binding inline">OPA LOCKA,</span>
             <span class="inline ng-binding">FL</span>
             <span class="inline ng-binding">33055-4314</span>
             <span ng-hide="isCountryUSA(property.mailingAddress.country)" class="ng-binding"></span>
     </div>
</td>
```

When I run this

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "ng-binding"]'):
    print(elem.text)
```

I get 7 values.

I want the 4 value which is: **1236 NW 167 ST**

How would I use the DOM hierarchy to only extract the address items so I can assign then to a variables.

Comment: How would you get 7 elements given the HTML in the question? There are only 2 elements whose class attribute matches exactly.

Comment: Ok This is only a snippet of the entire HTML. I was not going to post the entire page. My apologies I should have clarified that.

Comment: Is the desired address always the first `<span class="ng-binding">` element underneath a `<td class="pi_mailing_address">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the address from the 4<sup>th</sup> `<span>` you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `nth-child(4)`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.pi_mailing_address > strong +div span:nth-child(4)").text)
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `nth-of-type(4)`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.pi_mailing_address > strong +div span:nth-of-type(4)").text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `following`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Mailing Address']//following::div[1]//following::span[4]").text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `following-sibling`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Mailing Address']//following-sibling::div[1]//following::span[4]").text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```